# Route names starting with underscore in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-routing

I'm working on a Symfony2 project and in the file `routing.yml` I have the following lines:

```
_front:
    resource: routing_front.yml

_admin:
    resource: routing_admin.yml
    prefix:   /admin
```

So this actually allows defining the routes for the front-end and the back-end in separate dedicated files.

What about the names though ? Is it simply a naming convention to start with an underscore - which will tell at first sight that the actual routes are in a different file - or has this an influence on how the framework handle those ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a naming convention.

But the Framework will handle the routes by matching the first route defined with  the matching url requested, then the second one and so on...

So in your case, even if you requested `http://www.mysyte.com/admin/whatever`, it will match this url with all the routes in `routing_front.yml` before matching them with `routing_admin.yml`

Answer (score 0):

These names become particularly useful when you are creating links in twig templates - rather than hardcoding the URLs, you can generate absolute URLs based on the route names, e.g. :

```
<a href="{{ url('_welcome') }}">Welcome page</a>
```

The underscores make it more obviously a route, if you're a developer particularly far into Symfony-land (it is a convention), but they're definitely not *required* per se.

Comment: this is definitely not a recommended practice to prefix route names with underscores in general! As the accepted answer suggests, prefixed route names are a convention to mark "private" routes like the profiler which are not meant for "actual" use in userland.